# AEM 6.2 Issue in accessing page content using HTTP API

Tags: aem

We are working on a custom solution to use content from AEM instance. Using HTTP API(http://localhost:4502/api/content/sites/geometrixx/en.json) we can get details of page but not the content in a custom solution. I am wondering if using HTTP API we can also get page content. If no, which API we can use to get the content of pages. Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by “page content”? Pages are composed of multiple and nested components, what exactly on the page are you looking for?  And what is the intention of your solution?

Comment: We are working on a custom solution(out of AEM) which is using content present on few pages. We want to read all the nested component data present on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most pages you can make it end with ".infinity.json" to see all the details of the page.  You can also add numbers such as ".1.json" to see 1 level of info, or ".2.json" to see two levels of detail.  Some nodes are handled by specific servlets that may limit this behavior or give other options, but generally you can use this to view your own custom pages/nodes.

Also see

- https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/rendering-content-default-get-servlets.html#default-json-rendering
- https://gist.github.com/nateyolles/c683f8b39ca1e4688b38